# No unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `date_dimension` table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE date_dimension
(
  id integer primary key,
  date text,
  year double precision,
  year_for_week double precision,
  quarter double precision
);
```

I am trying to create a `fact` table that fails

```
create table fact ( 
  id serial primary key,
  contract integer,
  component integer,
  evaluation_date integer,
  effective_date integer,
  foreign key (evaluation_date, effective_date) references date_dimension(id, id)
);
```

The error is :

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced 
table "date_dimension"

SQL state: 42830
```

I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for two separate foreign keys:

```
foreign key (evaluation_date) references date_dimension(id),
foreign key (effective_date) references date_dimension(id)
```

Answer (score 15):

The error tells you the problem: You don't have a unique constraint on `date_dimension` that matches your foreign key constraint.

However, this leads to the bigger design problem: Your foreign key relationship doesn't make any sense.

You could possibly solve your "problem" with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX date_dimension(id,id);
```

But that's dumb, because `id` is always the same.  It could also be expressed as:

```
FOREIGN KEY (evaluation_date) REFERENCES date_dimension(id);
```

Then getting rid of the `effective_date` column, which would always be identical to `evaluation_date` in your example.

Or... you probably *really* want two FK relationships:

```
FOREIGN KEY (evaluation_date) REFERENCES date_dimension(id);
FOREIGN KEY (effective_date) REFERENCES date_dimension(id);
```

Comment: I have this error, and I can't make a constraint because we have duplicate rows in that table. Obviously Foreign Key is not what I want, but I'd like a constraint: "exists in this table", is that a possibility?

Comment: @isaaclw: There are ways to do that, but they usually aren't very pretty. You should ask another question (or search--I'm sure someone has already asked it here).

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just want to create two separate foreign key references to the date dimension as follows:

```
create table fact ( 
    id serial primary key,
    contract integer,
    component integer,
    evaluation_date integer,
    effective_date integer,
    foreign key (evaluation_date) references date_dimension(id),
    foreign key (effective_date) references date_dimension(id)
);
```