# How do I create a check to make sure a value exists in another table?

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

Right now I have two tables, one that contains a compound primary key and another that that references one of the values of the primary key but is a one-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Mapping`. The following is an idea of the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dev."Product"
(
  "Id" serial NOT NULL,
  "ShortCode" character(6),
  CONSTRAINT "ProductPK" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)

CREATE TABLE dev."Mapping"
(
  "LookupId" integer NOT NULL,
  "ShortCode" character(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "MappingPK" PRIMARY KEY ("LookupId", "ShortCode")
)
```

Since the `ShortCode` is displayed to the user as a six character string I don't want to have a another table to have a proper foreign key reference but trying to create one with the current design is [not allowed by PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317006/no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-referenced-table). As such, how can I create a check so that the short code in the `Mapping` table is checked to make sure it exists?

Comment: Please *always* provide your version of Postgres, especially with tricky db design questions.

Comment: A "1:M relationship between Product and Mapping" means Product is on the "one" side, and Mapping is on the "many" side. Is that really what you meant to say?

Comment: It's really unclear what's supposed to reference what and why neither "Product"."ShortCode" nor "Mapping"."ShortCode" can be declared `UNIQUE`. Your sentence `table ... is a one-to-many relationship between ...` does not make sense.

Comment: @rjzii: If it (which table?!) implements an n:m relationship, then we are dealing with at least three tables, but you only give two. Please clarify the whole thing.

Comment: For just that, consider the answer I already gave. But you really should revise your design. Building on a broken design will be a big, constant pain. A painful break is better than continued agony. Here is a complete code example for a proper n:m relationship: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225 And you still did not provide your version of Postgres, which should be the first, simple thing on your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the fine print of your requirements and your version of Postgres I would suggest a [`TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) or a [`NOT VALID` CHECK constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html).

We have just discussed the matter in depth in this related question on dba.SE:

- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/disable-all-constraints-and-table-checks-while-restoring-a-dump/75635)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you need a UNIQUE constraint on "Product"."ShortCode". Surely it should be declared NOT NULL, too.

```
CREATE TABLE dev."Product"
(
  "Id" serial NOT NULL,
  "ShortCode" character(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  CONSTRAINT "ProductPK" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

CREATE TABLE dev."Mapping"
(
  "LookupId" integer NOT NULL,
  "ShortCode" character(6) NOT NULL REFERENCES dev."Product" ("ShortCode"),
  CONSTRAINT "MappingPK" PRIMARY KEY ("LookupId", "ShortCode")
);
```

---

Your original "Product" table will allow this INSERT statement to succeed, but it shouldn't.

```
insert into dev."Product" ("ShortCode") values
(NULL), (NULL), ('ABC'), ('ABC'), ('ABC');
```

Data like that is just about useless.

```
select * from dev."Product"
```

```
id  ShortCode
--
1   
2   
3   ABC   
4   ABC   
5   ABC
```

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough, but `Product.ShortCode` has a one-to-many relationship on `Mapping.ShortCode` so the `UNIQUE` constraint wouldn't work. The example that you have with the `NULL` is what we are trying to avoid. Kind of a weird schema I know.

Comment: The code I wrote has a one-to-many relationship from Product.ShortCode to Mapping.ShortCode.