# Unable to explain this error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, create-table

**Background -** 
I'm extremely new to Postgres and SQL in general. I'm working my way through a homework task, where we have to take 6x .csv files containing data and conceptionlse them as tables in the form of a ERD, before exporting the ERD as SQL and running in Postgres.

**My SQL script -**
-- Staff Title Table

```
CREATE TABLE "titles" (
    "title_id" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    "title" VARCHAR   NOT NULL
);

-- Employees Table
CREATE TABLE "employees" (
    "emp_no" INT   NOT NULL,
    "emp_title_id" INT   NOT NULL,
    "birth_date" DATE   NOT NULL,
    "first_name" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    "last_name" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    "sex" INT   NOT NULL,
    "hire_date" DATE   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "pk_employees" PRIMARY KEY (
        "emp_no"
     )
);

-- Salaries Table
CREATE TABLE "salaries" (
    "emp_no" INT   NOT NULL,
    "salary" INT   NOT NULL
);

-- Department Manager
CREATE TABLE "dept_manager" (
    "dept_no" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    "emp_no" INT   NOT NULL
);

-- Department Numbers
CREATE TABLE "departments" (
    "dept_no" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    "dept_name" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "pk_departments" PRIMARY KEY (
        "dept_no"
     )
);

-- Employee vs. Department
CREATE TABLE "dept_emp" (
    "emp_no" INT   NOT NULL,
    "dept_no" VARCHAR   NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE "employees" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_employees_emp_title_id" FOREIGN KEY("emp_title_id")
REFERENCES "titles" ("title_id");

ALTER TABLE "salaries" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_salaries_emp_no" FOREIGN KEY("emp_no")
REFERENCES "employees" ("emp_no");

ALTER TABLE "dept_manager" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_dept_manager_dept_no" FOREIGN KEY("dept_no")
REFERENCES "departments" ("dept_no");

ALTER TABLE "dept_manager" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_dept_manager_emp_no" FOREIGN KEY("emp_no")
REFERENCES "employees" ("emp_no");

ALTER TABLE "dept_emp" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_dept_emp_emp_no" FOREIGN KEY("emp_no")
REFERENCES "employees" ("emp_no");

ALTER TABLE "dept_emp" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_dept_emp_dept_no" FOREIGN KEY("dept_no")
REFERENCES "departments" ("dept_no");
```

**Issue**
I export the SQL script fine, however when I run

```
ALTER TABLE "employees" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_employees_emp_title_id" FOREIGN KEY("emp_title_id")
REFERENCES "titles" ("title_id");
```

"I get the error message **ERROR:there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "titles" SQL state: 42830"**

**My thoughts -** 
...is that perhaps the name mismatch between the foreign key in the titles table (`title_id`) and it's primary key in the employees table (`emp_title_id`) is causing this issue. Both `title_id` and `emp_title_id` contain the same values (that being an employee id e.g S0002).

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317006/no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-referenced-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you. A foreign key can only reference a set of columns that is `unique`, or `primary key`. But the target of your foreign key, `titles(title_id)`, fails to meeting this requirement.

So basically you need to declare `title_id` as the primary key in the `titles` table to be able to create this foreign key.

You also need to align the datatypes between the columns (that's another requirement of foreign keys): as of now, `titles(title_id)` is declared as a string, while the referencing column is `INT`. Presumably, the source column should be `INT` too.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE titles (
    title_id int   NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_titles PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
);
```

With this fix, your entire code runs fine **[in this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aa2f80108830c54bb7b8baeba66bb746)**

Unrelated note: you should avoid double quoting all the identifers; it does not help, and might make things more complicated later on.

Comment: Thank you for the useful pointer about double quoting (bad habit) and of course putting me right.

Answer (score 0):

In the table `"titles"` you forgot to define the primary key. Therefore you cannot create a foreign key against this table.

To fix this, the table definition should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE "titles" (
    "title_id" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    "title" VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "pk_titles" PRIMARY KEY (
        "title_id"
     )
);
```

Comment: I appreciate your input with the answer also. Such a silly simple thing.